# How to process annotations with Maven?

Tags: java, maven-2, maven, annotations, apt

I'm trying to process annotations with my own annotations processor in a maven project. Using org.bsc.maven:maven-processor-plugin I had some success, but many problems.
I wonder if there is a demo project comparable to my usage scenario I could compare to.

Comment: This is not how asking SO questions works. What are your problems (please post maven output, stack traces etc.)?. You can't expect users here to take the time to toy with your sample project if you don't say what's wrong.

Comment: the question was to post a sample annotations processing maven project. Not to solve my individual problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Surprisingly all what was needed is adding a dependency on the project with the annotation processor.

[dp4jmaventest](http://code.google.com/p/dp4j/downloads/detail?name=dp4jmaventest.zip) is a sample project for dp4j annotations processor.

My problem was that of trying to process annotations in classes within the same annotation processing project. The solution is to compile on two phases.

```
</configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-compile</id>
                    <configuration>
                        <compilerArgument>-proc:none</compilerArgument>
                        <includes>
                            <include>com/dp4j/**</include>
                            <include>com/dp4j/processors/core/**</include>
                            <include>com/dp4j/processors/**</include>
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>compile-everything-else</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
<!--http://cdivilly.wordpress.com/2010/03/16/maven-and-jsr-269-annotation-processors/-->
```

[dp4j maven project](http://code.google.com/p/dp4j/source/checkout) is a working example project.